# Using cartographer for creating map, how?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, cartographer, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I just installed cartographer package and I am trying to use it in order to create a map and visualise it in rviz.
I am using vrep, where I have a robot with laser scan publishing data to laser scan topic and odometry data to odom topic.
I am trying to make the cartographer_node to subscribe to these topics and produce the map, just like I did with gmapping before.

However I am lost in the launch files and in how I pass these parameters to cartographer. I am in beginner level. I have read the ros tutorials but still it doesn't make sense. Could anyone provide me with an example of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252104/using-cartographer-for-creating-map,-how??/) by [SCrusher](https://answers.ros.org/users/28965/scrusher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
you need a IMU topic that publich /imu msg. I d'ont know, if you can use it only with /scan and /odom topic
you have to change the configuration in your backpack_2d.lua.

use_laser_scan = true,
use_multi_echo_laser_scan = false,

read this:
https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

---

Originally posted by [farhatm](https://answers.ros.org/users/29030/farhatm/) with karma: 28 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1